# How to save the spotify user access token from a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify

I know this may be very simple but I am trying to figure out my way through the Spotify api, and am having some difficulty with the code. I made a call to set Spotify's `clientId` and `clientSecret`. However, once I set and have the access token in my promise, it wont tell me actually make a request to get a song or artist. I realized it is because a promise is async and the code continues while it runs in background(hence async). So I added the async and await feature to it but even after this my code still does not run as it should. I am trying to run this as a node.js file, so I run the command `node app.js` when I am ready. I can't seem to grab the data and set it. Any help would be appreciated.

**Code:**

```
const SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');



var clientId = {my-id},        //Placeholder
  clientSecret = {my-secret};   //Placeholder

// Create the api object with the credentials
let spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
  clientId: clientId,
  clientSecret: clientSecret
});

// Retrieve an access token.

const spotify = async() => {
  await spotifyApi.clientCredentialsGrant()
  .then(data => {
      console.log('The access token expires in ' + data.body['expires_in']);
      console.log('The access token is ' + data.body['access_token']);
  
      // Save the access token so that it's used in future calls
      spotifyApi.setAccessToken(data.body['access_token']);

      
  
  })
  .catch(err => {
      console.log('Something went wrong when retrieving an access token', err);
  });
}


//I want to do stuff with the code but it does not know the access token at this point still
// Get an artist
spotifyApi.getArtist('2hazSY4Ef3aB9ATXW7F5w3')
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log('Artist information', data.body);
  }, function(err) {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

**Error:**

```
[Error [WebapiError]: Unauthorized] { statusCode: 401 }
```

So again I realize the error is coming from the fact that it is async but I just for some reason can't think of the way to solve this problem I am having.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a request to get a song or artist after you have made a call to set Spotify's clientId and clientSecret by chaining another **then** block to the promise
Then moving the song or artist request into that **then** block

I hope this helps

```
const SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');

var clientId = {my-id},        //Placeholder
  clientSecret = {my-secret};   //Placeholder

// Create the api object with the credentials
let spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
  clientId: clientId,
  clientSecret: clientSecret
});

// Retrieve an access token.

const spotify = async() => {
  await spotifyApi.clientCredentialsGrant()
  .then(data => {
      console.log('The access token expires in ' + data.body['expires_in']);
      console.log('The access token is ' + data.body['access_token']);
  
      // Save the access token so that it's used in future calls
      spotifyApi.setAccessToken(data.body['access_token']);
  })
  .then(() => {
      // do stuff with the code here
      // Get an artist or Song here
      spotifyApi.getArtist('2hazSY4Ef3aB9ATXW7F5w3')
       .then(function(data) {
            console.log('Artist information', data.body);
        }, function(err) {
            console.error(err);
      });

  })
  .catch(err => {
      console.log('Something went wrong when retrieving an access token', err);
  });
}
```

Comment: You can get git rid of the async - await with this approach

Comment: Thank you, it worked, once I removed the async and await I previously put in the code.